# Using client in other files than main file

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm a very new discord.js coder. I have been trying to use this code in a different file, `\modules\verifyForm.js`, and it always comes up with `client is not defined`. I've had quite a large look around and it always comes up with something that is too outdated, something very advanced or something that just don't work.

I have a separate main file in `\index.js` in which this piece of code works. Client is defined in that file or course, but because you can't have two instances I can't re-define it. Am I just being dumb or is there a better way to do this. Would a collection or using exports help?

```
const { ActionRowBuilder, Events, InteractionType, ModalBuilder, TextInputBuilder, TextInputStyle, } = require('discord.js');

client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async (interaction) => {
    if (interaction.isButton()) {
        if (interaction.customId === 'verification-button') {
        const modal = new ModalBuilder()
            .setCustomId('verification-modal')
            .setTitle('Verify yourself')
            .addComponents([
            new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
                new TextInputBuilder()
                .setCustomId('verification-input')
                .setLabel('Answer')
                .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
                .setMinLength(0)
                .setMaxLength(512)
                .setPlaceholder('ABCDEF')
                .setRequired(true),
            ),
            ]);

        await interaction.showModal(modal);
        }
}

if (interaction.type === InteractionType.ModalSubmit) {
    if (interaction.customId === 'verification-modal') {
    const response =
        interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('verification-input');
    interaction.channel(`Yay, your answer is submitted: "${response}"`);
    }
}
});
```

I do have a separate embed with the button attached.

If you do have a way to get around using client or if you have a way to fix the error, thanks.

Comment: Export a function from verifyForm into index, then pass the client as a parameter into that function and invoke it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make the client a global variable so you can use it everywhere, basically `global.client = new Client()`

Comment: I'm going to need some more info, how am I declaring global?

Comment: `var client = new Client()` is a normal variable, if you add `global.` instead of `var` it becomes a global variable, the global variables can be used in any file, in any folder, you will still use `client` after creating it, https://stackabuse.com/using-global-variables-in-node-js/ here more about global variables